# Problem with data member update in recursive function call

Tags: c++, recursion, game-engine

I'm probably not seeing the obvious. I have an object hierarchy and want to apply a transform to all geometric objects in the hierarchy. The base class Node is as follows:

```
class Node
{
    Matrix4 node_matrix;

    // ... other stuff
}
```

It contains a baseline matrix node_matrix, that gets modified by the program:

```
for (size_t a = 0; a < level.objects.size(); ++a)
{
     ApplyTransform(level.objects[a].node_matrix);
     level.objects[a].Update(level.objects[a].node_matrix);
     // ... do more stuff
}
```

objects[a] is a GameObject and the root node, its matrix gets modified by ApplyTransform(). I then call the update method on the root node using the recursive function Update() defined in the class below:

```
class GameObject : public Node
{
public:
    GameObject *parent;
    std::vector<GameObject*> children;
    Matrix4 current_node_matrix;
    GeometryNode *geometry;
       
    //Default ctor
    GameObject() : parent(nullptr) {}
    
    //Copy ctor and assignment
    GameObject(const GameObject&) = default;
    GameObject& operator=(const GameObject&) = default;
    
    //Move ctor and assignment
    GameObject(GameObject &&) = default;
    GameObject& operator=(GameObject &&) = default;
    
    //Default dtor
    ~GameObject() = default;
    
    void Update(Matrix4 nm)
    {
        if (parent != nullptr)
        {
            current_node_matrix = nm * node_matrix;
        }
        else
        {
            current_node_matrix = nm;
        }
          
        for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i)
        {
            children[i]->Update(current_node_matrix);
        }
    }
};
```

This works fine but I thought I could avoid passing a matrix to the Update() method by simply writing;

```
void GameObject::Update()
{
     if (parent != nullptr)
     {
         current_node_matrix = parent->current_node_matrix * node_matrix;
     }
     else
     {
         current_node_matrix = node_matrix;
     }
          
     for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i)
     {
         children[i]->Update();
     }
}
```

I verified that current_node_matrix gets indeed modified as expected in the first call (of the root node), but when using

```
parent->current_node_matrix
```

in the recursive call the child sees the original (non-modified) matrix. I verified a number of things and just don't understand why the current_node_matrix gets correctly updated in the parent object but is not visible to the child object (the parent pointers point to the correct objects, I checked that too).

I probably don't see the elephant in the room. Any thoughts?

I add a fully functional reproducible example below. This does basically the same thing than in the code and fails in the same way: Calling Update1 works, whereas calling Update2 fails.

Thanks in advance,

Kris

MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum class Matrix4Type {identity};

class Matrix4
{
public:
    
    float M[4][4]{0};
    
    //Default ctor
    Matrix4() = default;
    
    Matrix4(Matrix4Type);
    
    //Copy ctor and assignment
    Matrix4(const Matrix4&) = default;
    
    Matrix4& operator=(const Matrix4&) = default;
    
    //Move ctor and assignment
    Matrix4(Matrix4&&) = default;
    Matrix4& operator=(Matrix4&&) = default;
    
    friend Matrix4 operator*(const Matrix4& mult1, const Matrix4& mult2);
    Matrix4 operator*(const float scale);
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix4 &m);
    
};

Matrix4::Matrix4(Matrix4Type mtype)
{
    switch (mtype)
    {
        case Matrix4Type::identity:
        {
            M[0][0] = 1.0f;
            M[1][1] = 1.0f;
            M[2][2] = 1.0f;
            M[3][3] = 1.0f;
            break;
        }
    }
}

Matrix4 operator*(const Matrix4& mult1, const Matrix4& mult2)
{
    Matrix4 retmat;
    
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            for (uint8_t k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
            {
                retmat.M[i][j] += mult1.M[i][k] * mult2.M[k][j];
            }
        }
     }
    
    return retmat;
}

Matrix4 Matrix4::operator*(const float scale)
{
    Matrix4 retmat = *this;
    
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            retmat.M[i][j] *= scale;
        }
    }
    
    return retmat;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix4 &m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            os << m.M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
    
    os << "-------" << std::endl;
    return os;
}


class Node
{
public:
    Matrix4 node_matrix;
    
    //Default ctor
    Node() = default;
    
    //Custom ctor
    Node(const Matrix4 &m) : node_matrix(m) { }
    
    //Copy ctor and assignment
    Node(const Node &pt) = default;
    Node& operator=(const Node &pt) = default;
    
    //Move ctor and assignment
    Node(Node &&mv) = default;
    Node& operator=(Node &&mv) = default;
    
    //Default dtor
    ~Node() = default;
    
    
    inline void ApplyTransform(const Matrix4 &trans) noexcept
    {
        node_matrix = node_matrix * trans;
    }
    
};


class GameObject : public Node
{
public:
    GameObject *parent;
    std::vector<GameObject*> children;
    Matrix4 current_node_matrix;
    
    //Default ctor
    GameObject() : parent(nullptr) {}
    
    //Copy ctor and assignment
    GameObject(const GameObject&) = default;
    GameObject& operator=(const GameObject&) = default;
    
    //Move ctor and assignment
    GameObject(GameObject &&) = default;
    GameObject& operator=(GameObject &&) = default;
    
    //Default ctor
    ~GameObject() = default;
    
    void Update1(Matrix4 nm)
    {
        if (parent != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Parent" << std::endl << nm << std::endl;
            current_node_matrix = nm * node_matrix;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Root" << std::endl;
            current_node_matrix = nm;
        }
        
        std::cout << current_node_matrix << std::endl;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i)
        {
            children[i]->Update1(current_node_matrix);
        }
    }
    
    void Update2()
    {
        if (parent != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Parent" << std::endl << parent->current_node_matrix << std::endl;
            current_node_matrix = parent->current_node_matrix * node_matrix;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Root" << std::endl;
            current_node_matrix = node_matrix;
        }
        
        std::cout << current_node_matrix << std::endl;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i)
        {
            children[i]->Update2();
        }
    }
    
    void AddChild(GameObject *toadd)
    {
        toadd->parent = this;
        children.push_back(toadd);
    }
    
    void SetCoordinateSystem(const Matrix4&m)
    {
        node_matrix = m;
    
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    
    std::vector<GameObject> objects;
    GameObject base1, child1, child2, second_child1;
    
    Matrix4 temp1 = Matrix4(Matrix4Type::identity);
    Matrix4 temp2 = Matrix4(Matrix4Type::identity) * 2.0f;
    
    base1.SetCoordinateSystem(temp1);
    child1.SetCoordinateSystem(temp1);
    child2.SetCoordinateSystem(temp1);
    second_child1.SetCoordinateSystem(temp1);
    
    base1.AddChild(&child1);
    base1.AddChild(&child2);
    child2.AddChild(&second_child1);
    
    objects.push_back(base1);
    
    objects[0].ApplyTransform(temp2);
    
    objects[0].Update1(objects[0].node_matrix);
    //objects[0].Update2();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's me who doesn't see the obvious, but why is `GameObject` a `Node`? How come you've `default`:ed  "the big 5!" when (I think) you have owning pointers? It's too hard for me to say what's going on without a [mre] I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack overflow, I was not precise enough. ```Node``` and ```GameObject``` here are trivially copyable since pointers are not owning anything (just observers). Data is owned separately by the ```GeometryNode.```. That's why I default the big 5. Will work on a minimal reproducible example, but may take some time (not used to it). Many thanks in any case.

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look into your MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE.
`Update2()` is fine.

The problem lies on the `vector<GameObject> objects`.
When you do `objects.push_back(base1)`, instead of holding `base1`, a behavior you would have expected, `objects` makes a new object copying `base1` and then contains the new object.

To use the vector container, I suggest you would either

1. make `objects` to contain the pointers to the game object (`vector<GameObject*> objects`)
2. make hierarchy after you contains your game objects in the `objects`.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I was missing something obvious. I create base1 and attach the address of base1 to the children, and when pushing into the vector the address of the children gets copied correctly, but I I am still pointing to base1 and not the copy in the vector as the parent. Seems trivial now that I figured it out.